# How to index only end dates in the aggregated field in the search api?

Tags: search, 9

I have two date range fields on two different content types. I want to index only the end date of both of the date range fields.

I can do it by simply clicking the plus icon on the field and add the end date only.

[image]

But this is not possible in the aggregate fields. In the aggregate fields.

I have a union on both date fields. But there isn't an option to select the end dates only?

Is it possible to index only end dates from both the fields in one field as aggregated field? (

Comment: This is currently not supported, but there is a workaround by hacking the YAML config files, see issues [3018079](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/3018079) and [2693071](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/2693071).

Comment: @Hudri currently the field is assigned like `entity:node/date_time`, so how I will change it to assign the end date? i-e  `entity:node/date_time:end_value`?

Comment: Not tried, but yes, that's the theory